# Blender 2.81a cannot render anything

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I installed the newest version of blender on my new computer made a scene and tried to render with a camera setup and it just shows up blank. I checked if the camera is turned on for rendering and it is.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Are you sure you pressed F12 to render? It seems you just opened your render slots (F11).

Comment: Thanks alot omg. I had the keybind changed on my old computer.